# Tensor matricizations and their decompositions

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra, tensor

Suppose we have a 4-index tensor $t_{ijkl}$ (all 4 dimensions are equal size). We can make a matrix out of it by taking first and last two indexes as new indexes: $t_{ijkl} \rightarrow M_{ij, kl}$. Suppose we have an SVD of this matrix $M = U S V^\dagger$. Now we take another matricization of $t$, such that $t_{ijkl} \rightarrow N_{ik, jl}$. Can we say anything about the SVD of $N$ from the SVD of $M$?
More precise, here are two questions I would like to answer

1. Assuming the rank of M is R1, how can the rank of N be estimated?
2. Is there a map between singular vectors of M and N, and if so how can it be built?

Comment: Do you know the paper [A multilinear singular value decomposition](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0895479896305696)? It gives some nice insight about SVD of tensors unfoldings.

Comment: @Surb I've read it some time ago, but thank you for bringing this point

Comment: Just following on the idea of using multilinear SVD (HOSVD). In HOSVD the tensor is decomposed to a "core" tensor and orthogonal factor matrices along each dimension. $t_{ijkl} = \sum_{abcd} \sigma_{abcd} U_{ai} V_{bj} W_{ck} Y_{dl}$. Permuting the original tensor would mean permuting the core tensor and the order of factor matrices. However, I don't see how the core tensor from HOSVD is connected to the singular value matrix $S$ of $M$. In fact, if we set the size of the dimensions to be $n$, $\sigma$ can have up to $n^4$ elements, whereas $S$ will have only $n^2$ at most

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure how to answer this question right now because it is so general. For example, yes, the SVD of $N$ can be calculated using the SVD of $M$: use the SVD of $M$ to reconstruct $M$ itself, which can be used to construct $N$, which can be used to get the SVD of $N$. Of course, this certainly isn't what you actually want, but I'm not really sure what you *do* want either.

It seems like you're perhaps interested in how the realignment map from quantum entanglement affects the singular values of a matrix. Is this correct?

Comment: @Nathaniel Johnston, thanks for commenting. Indeed, I'm interested in this problem because it's relation to quantum entanglement. I've corrected the question to clarify it

Comment: @Nathaniel Johnston
Oh, I've found your paper here http://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.5853 :)

Comment: @qbit- For question 1, I'm not quite sure... you can get some very extreme behavior, but I'm not sure about the intermediate behavior. For example, if rank(M) = 1, it could be the case that rank(N) = 1 or rank(N) = n^2 (the largest possible value: n is the dimension of each of the 4 tensor indices). For one extreme, let N be the n^2-by-n^2 identity matrix: then M has rank 1. However, it's not clear to me (for example) whether or not it's possible that if rank(M) = 3 then rank(N) could be arbitrary.

If you're interested in absolute separability/ever want to discuss it, feel free to e-mail me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer, but there has been some movement regarding this topic.
I humbly recommend to look into the article https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.08437 and in particular the citations therein.

There is also a segment about the equivalence of the tensor feasibility and the quantum marginal problem, which might be interesting depending on ones background.

The connection between the two matricization given in your example however turns out to be a bit more difficult to categorize. On the other hand, regarding the connection of singular values of $M_{i,jk\ell}$, $M_{ij,k\ell}$ and $M_{ijk,\ell}$, the problem is basically completely solved.